# Zeppelin Hive ParseException

Tags: hive, apache-zeppelin

I am using Zeppelin with Hive on Hortonworks HDP2.5 clusters, and I have two questions :

1. Zeppelin parse exception

when I run hive query in Zeppelin , there will be a parse exception if the line is end by ';' , for example :

when I run in zeppelin ,

```
%jdbc(hive) 
show tables;
```

there is an error as shown below

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:11 extraneous input ';' expecting EOF near '<EOF>'
class org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException
org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccess(Utils.java:262)
org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccessWithInfo(Utils.java:248)
org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.runAsyncOnServer(HiveStatement.java:297)
org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:238)
org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.executeSql(JDBCInterpreter.java:356)
org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.interpret(JDBCInterpreter.java:442)
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:94)
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:341)
org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:176)
org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.ParallelScheduler$JobRunner.run(ParallelScheduler.java:162)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

but when I run in zeppelin,

```
%jdbc(hive) 
show tables
```

it works well without errors.

2. the second question is that if Zeppelin can run multiple hive queries within just one segment ?

If yes, how to write the multiple hive queries ? for example ( USE database ; SHOW tables; )

PS :

The jar packages under /zeppelin/interpreter/jdbc are shown in below

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 zeppelin zeppelin  2172168 Aug 26 11:58 guava-15.0.jar
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 zeppelin zeppelin  3607775 Dec 26 13:48 hadoop-common-2.7.3.2.5.0.0-1245.jar
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root     root     20087903 Dec 27 12:44 hive-jdbc-1.2.1000.2.5.0.0-1245-standalone.jar
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 zeppelin zeppelin   213911 Aug 26 11:58 jline-2.12.1.jar
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 zeppelin zeppelin   489884 Aug 26 11:58 log4j-1.2.17.jar
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 zeppelin zeppelin   648487 Aug 26 11:58 postgresql-9.4-1201-jdbc41.jar
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 zeppelin zeppelin   533455 Dec 26 13:46 protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 zeppelin zeppelin    32119 Aug 26 11:58 slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 zeppelin zeppelin     8866 Aug 26 11:58 slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 zeppelin zeppelin    31273 Aug 26 11:58 zeppelin-jdbc-0.6.0.2.5.0.0-1245.jar
```

Any help is really appreciated !

thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Zeppelin parse exception

   - It's normal behaviour because JDBC interpreter runs like a client program(You can refer to ***JDBC Client Sample Code***
     in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients)
2. multiple hive queries in one paragraph

   - Zeppelin doesn't support multiple queries in one paragrph so you can now one query in one pargraph.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade to new version(Zeppelin 0.7.2) will fix the two question.

If do not want to upgrade, I suggest you read zeppelin source code and make some modification on class JDBCInterpreter.